Why is my two port Realtek PCIe Ethernet card installing a 3rd controller in Windows 11?
I am using a two port PCIe ethernet card from StarTech. I never had problems with this card on Windows 10 but since moving to Windows 11, after a few reboots it installed a 3rd controller, which can be seen in the device manager. Upon reboot, one of the 3 controllers will become hidden. After each reboot the hidden controller will sometimes change. It seems to flip between 1 and 3. In the image below you can see that Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller is hidden (View > Show hidden devices).

The problem is I have configured 1 port to use a specific IP address. If the controller associated with that port disappears (becomes hidden) then the device that is connected to that port no longer works as the controller it switched to was not configured. If I continue to reboot, sometimes I get the right combination of controllers so the device works again.
If you look at the events for the controller you can see that it requested an install just prior to this issue starting.

The default driver is a Microsoft driver, but you can also install the Realtek driver. At first I thought a driver could be the problem, but I have reproduced this with both the Microsoft driver and the Realtek driver. If I completely uninstall all the controllers and the driver, then scan for changes, it comes back with just two controllers using the Microsoft driver. However after several reboots, I am back to a situation with 3 controllers.
Any ideas what could be causing this and how I can prevent it?
